# Apache FOP keeping two elements together not working

Tags: apache, xslt

I have following xslt:

```
  <xsl:template match="P">
    <fo:block>
      1.1 First Image
    </fo:block>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="figure">
        <fo:block margin-top="-0.30in"  keep-with-previous.within-page="always">
              <fo:external-graphic>
                 <xsl:attribute name="src"> <xsl:value-of select="abc.svg" />
                  </xsl:attribute>
              </fo:external-graphic>
            </fo:block>
 </xsl:template>
```

Both these templates will be called in a recursive method.

**My output is :**
P tag is coming in one page where it has space. Since figures are big, it shows in the next page. I want them to be together.

**Tried solutions**: keep-with, break-after, page-break-after.

Keep-with is not working. Others are creating new page for every P tag though there is space in the previous tag.
I am generating PDF output using FOP1.0.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<xsl:template match="P">
    <fo:block>
        1.1 First Image
    </fo:block>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="P">
    <fo:block keep-with-next.within-page="always">
        1.1 First Image
    </fo:block>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Joel, This also did not work for me. P tag is still in one page and figure in the next page. And there is alot of space above every figure in pdf. approx upto 0.71inches which is not looking good.

Comment: Try reading this (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tippgbk/index.html?ca=drs). It's an old article, but it may help.

Comment: Ya. I have seen this link. They say 'keep' properties are only supported in a table row. But my xslt is very dynamic. I have 50 tags for which I have written templates and they will be called only by xsl:apply-templates /. So I cannot create a table to use 'keep'.Please help me with any other solution.

Comment: I used  keep-with-previous="always". And it worked. Thank you:)